# Filter specific message dates using email activity csv request using SQL syntax

Tags: rest, sendgrid

Currently the csv I am requesting brings more than the limit that email activity offers(1,000,000) and I am missing data of the recent days.

I've tried using a query string with this example
[Query processed dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnEt4.png)

but I am getting that message. I want to know what I'm doing wrong and how do I fix the request to get specifically data from the dates I am filtering.